# Simple Java integer and long arithmetics

Tags: java, int, long-integer

Simple code no problem

```
long x =  Integer.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.println(x * 2 + "...." + Long.MAX_VALUE);

= 4294967294....9223372036854775807
```

but what is happening here? why -2

```
System.out.println(2 * Integer.MAX_VALUE + "...." + Long.MAX_VALUE);
=   -2....9223372036854775807
```

and why elements is 149998, doesn't the compiler converts these to long?

```
    long elements = 2 * Integer.MAX_VALUE + 150000;
System.out.println(elements + "...." + Long.MAX_VALUE);
149998....9223372036854775807
```

-thanks

Comment: Where would it know to convert?  In the third expression, you don't use a `long` at all....and in the second, you don't use one til it's too late.

Comment: Why do you think this is happening?  Why shouldn't it do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
and why elements is 149998, doesn't the compiler converts these to long?
```

It does, but only *after* the arithmetic.  So you've got int*int + int, which is an int.  It will then cast it to a long.  However, at this point you've got an integer overflow (i.e. it went beyond the bounds of an integer)

you need to convert the numbers of the right to a long first

```
long elements = 2L * Integer.MAX_VALUE + 150000;
```

or

```
long elements = 2 * (long)Integer.MAX_VALUE + 150000;
```

B

Answer (score 6):

Promote variables from integer to long.

```
long elements = 2 * Integer.MAX_VALUE + 150000;
```

should be

```
long elements = 2L * Integer.MAX_VALUE + 150000;
```

The evaluation of original statement,

```
long elements = 2 * Integer.MAX_VALUE + 150000;
```

is equivalent to

```
long elements = (long)(2 * Integer.MAX_VALUE + 150000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE =2147483647=01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

And

```
2*Integer.MAX_VALUE=4294967294=2*(01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111)  
                              =this will result a 33-bit value
```

But in Java `int` can represent maximum of 32bit.

Comment: also its singed, ergo the minus value

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment yet :(.

The Oracle Java Tutorials confirmed that it will convert the data to the primitive type long. Since you're adding an int and a long, the compiler will add the data before it converts it to a long. If you really want it to be a long the entire time, you'd have to type cast.

EX;

```
 // (long) is typcasted
long elements = 2 * (long) Integer.MAX_VALUE + 150000;

//prints elements as a long t + "" + max value
System.out.println(elements + "...." + Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

Type is casting preformed by adding the wanted primitive type in front of the current data type.